# Squid doesn't block non-ascii domans

Tags: unicode, squid

I have the following lines in `/etc/squid/squid.conf`:

```
acl bad_url url_regex "/etc/squid/block.acl"
http_access deny bad_url
```

All of the urls in `block.acl` must be blocked by the proxy server. It works for all ASCII domains, but when I add a non-ascii domain such as `helfende-hände.de` to `/etc/squid/block.acl`, the domain is not blocked.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ASCII Punycode version of the domain name instead:

```
xn--helfende-hnde-kfb.de
```